# Drupal_get_title() but for another field by name?

Tags: 7, entities

If I use `drupal_get_title()` I can print the title of the page to the page body. Custom content types that I'm using have many fields like subtitle, url redirects, etc. How would I go about printing those to the page body just like `drupal_get_title()` allows me to do for the page title?

I've reviewed the forum for other solutions. `field_get_items()` and `$content['field_name']` aren't working for me. I think what I want to do is simple but most of the examples pertain to database manipulation.

Comment: Please update the question with your code you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `print $content['field_MACHINE_NAME']['und'][0][taxonomy_term]->name;`? That should print the field without the HTML

If you want the HTML, trying using `print render($content['field_review_nationality'][0]);`

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/1323842)